# Laravel 5.7 sending notifications using Expo

Tags: laravel, expo, laravel-5.7, laravel-notification

I'm using Laravel 5.7 for my backend (I'm new to Laravel) and I'm trying to use [Expo push notification extension for Laravel](https://github.com/Alymosul/laravel-exponent-push-notifications) to send notifications to my users.

I followed the steps explained, but I get lost to where I'm suppose to place the `class ExpoNotification extends Notification` and how to call it.

What I expect to happen is that every time an orders status get changed a notification is send to the user.

What is happening is that I get an error saying the `class` can't be found.

**OrderController**

```
    public function update_order(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //Get the Order and update the status
        Order::where('id', '=', $id )->update($request->only(['status']));

        //Get the order with ::find so I can use $order-> 
        $order = Order::find($id);

        //Get user belonging to this order
        $user= User::where('id', '=', $order->user_id);

        //Get response with orders only posted the same day and are payed
        $orders = Order::where('store_id', '=', $order->store_id)
          ->where('day', '=', $order->day )
          ->where('week', '=', $order->week )
          ->where('year', '=', $order->year )
          ->where('payment_status', '=', $order->payment_status)->get();

        //send expo notification so the user gets his update
        new ExpoNotification($order);

        //return only relevant orders to the store
      return  OrderResource::collection($orders);
    }
```

**ExpoNotification**

```
<?
namespace App\Notifications\ExpoNotification;
use App\Order;
use App\User;
use NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\ExpoChannel;
use NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\ExpoMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class ExpoNotification extends Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [ExpoChannel::class];
    }

    public function toExpoPush($notifiable)
    {
        return ExpoMessage::create()
            ->badge(1)
            ->enableSound()
            ->body("Your {$notifiable->service} account was approved!");
    }
}
```

**Error from postman**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--


Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class &#039;App\Notifications\ExpoNotification&#039; not found in file /Users/salmanmohamed/Documents/apps/rapiobackend/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php on line 182
Stack trace:
 1. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError-&gt;() /Users/salmanmohamed/Documents/apps/rapiobackend/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:182
```

**Answer**
Provided by Mohammed

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Order;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\ExpoChannel;
use NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\ExpoMessage;

class ExNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $order;
    public function __construct($order){
    $this->order=$order;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [ExpoChannel::class];
    }

    public function toExpoPush($notifiable)
    {
        return ExpoMessage::create()
            ->badge(1)
            ->enableSound()
            ->body("Your {$notifiable->service} account was approved!");
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you get Push token after migration and use it when send a notification to a specific device? I can't figure out how to do so and the code provided doesn't include any reference to any keys ... thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your wrong is your implementation of your `ExpoNotification` class it's namespace is `App\Expo` and you are using `App\Notifications\ExpoNotification`

Comment: Thanks for your response, changing the `namespace` still gives me the same error. `Class &#039;App\Notifications\ExpoNotification&#039; not found in file /Users/salmanmohamed/Documents/apps/rapiobackend/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php on line 188`

Comment: do you have anydesk or team viewer?

Comment: Yes, anyway to DM me?

Comment: please send me your id of team viewer

Comment: hi i have follow all the process but still not receive any push notification in reat can anyone help?

Comment: hi, have you received push notification?